# What are the ESSs among hawks, doves, retaliators, bully and prober retaliators?

Tags: evolution, evolutionary-game-theory

In his book "[The Selfish Gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Selfish_Gene)", Richard Dawkins says that retaliator emerges as an evolutionary stable strategy. But I think dove is also a kind of retaliator and so if dove increases,  the hawks and others can exploit them.

Is retaliator an ESS? If not, which strategy is ESS?

**Definitions:**

- hawk : They always fight hard and retreat only when injured.
- doves : They merely threaten in a dignified way and never hurt anyone.

If a hawk fights a dove, dove runs away. If dove meets dove they go on posturing until one of them is tired and retreats. If a hawk meets hawk they fight until someone gets seriously injured or dies.

- retaliators : A retaliator plays dove at the beginning of every fight. If opponent attacks, he attacks , if opponent behave like a dove he behaves like a dove. When 2 retaliators meet they behave like doves.
- bully : A bully behave like a hawk until someone hits back. Then, he runs away.
- prober retaliator : He is like a retaliator but he tries a brief escalation of the contest. He is hawk like if opponent doesn't strike back. If opponent strikes back he behave like a dove. If he is attacked he retaliates.

The pay offs: 50 for winning, 0 for losing, -100 for being seriously injured. and -10 for wasting time in a long contest.

Source: [The Selfish Gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Selfish_Gene)

Comment: Why would you label the dove a kind of retaliator?

Comment: Could you please describe the kind of payoff matrix in play and the definition of the different strategies (dove, hawk, retaliator)?

Comment: @fileunderwater As retaliators play like doves at the beginning of every fight and 2 doves do exactly the same thing as 2 retaliators will do when they meet.

Comment: @remi.b Sure. Will edit the question----

Comment: @biogirl But that is the whole point of the *retaliator* - that they behave as *dove* initially, but then retaliates. *Doves* don't retaliate (they always back down if challanged) so I dont see the point of labelling them as "*...a kind of retaliator*".

Comment: @biogirl Also, I think you should limit your question to one particular evolutionary game. Your question now refers to five different strategies (which can also have various payoff schemes), and to analyse all these is too much for a single question. Are you most interested in the hawk-dove-retaliator game?

Comment: @fileunderwater But when two retaliators meet they behave exactly as if two doves are meeting.

Comment: @fileunderwater I am actually interested in choosing out of all these five.

Comment: @biogirl Well, I think the question is too vague and broad. If you want to compare all five categories, you should also assign payoffs between all "encounters" more clearly, since this will ultimately determine the ESSs.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dawkins answers this in the book as well.

The point was that most strategies are not stable because the "random" introduction/mutation/evolution of some alternate strategies will disrupt a population of the first strategy.

The example was a group of doves being invaded by a single hawk (the conspiracy of doves). Because the hawk does relatively better (by winning every conflict against a dove), than even after generations of entirely doves, the random addition of a hawk (say by mutation) will take hold because the hawk always wins against a dove. Whatever feature/gene that created a hawk in the pool of doves will be passed to some offspring.

If I remember correctly, the only stable case was prober-retaliator, since all others get invaded by someone else.

Comment: Yeah he has answered it in the newer editions....